# How to change the variable from inside Fn closure in Rust?

Tags: rust, closures, mutability

I have the following code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=33ca64c1f7b3cd776dbf91cc7bdff6ff&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
struct A {
    pub vec: Vec<u64>,
}

impl A {
    fn perform_for_all<F: Fn(&mut u64)>(&mut self, f: F) {
        for mut i in &mut self.vec {
            f(i);
        }
    }
}
fn main() {
    let mut a = A {
        vec: vec![1, 3, 44, 2, 4, 5, 6],
    };

    let mut done = false;

    a.perform_for_all(|v| {
        println!("value: {:?}", v);
        done = true;
    });

    if !done {
        a.perform_for_all(|v| {
            println!("value {:?}", v);
        });
    }
}
```

The following errors occur:

```
error[E0594]: cannot assign to `done`, as it is a captured variable in a `Fn` closure
  --> src/main.rs:21:9
   |
21 |         done = true;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot assign
   |
help: consider changing this to accept closures that implement `FnMut`
  --> src/main.rs:19:23
   |
19 |       a.perform_for_all(|v| {
   |  _______________________^
20 | |         println!("value: {:?}", v);
21 | |         done = true;
22 | |     });
   | |_____^
```

I have a list of loaded objects and a list of objects in a database. I need a function that takes a closure and executes it on the loaded objects and if we don't have the objects in the list, execute it on a list of objects from the database.

That function looks like:

```
pub fn perform_for_match_with_mark<F>(&mut self, mark: MatchMark, f: F)
where
    F: Fn(&mut GameMatch),
{
    self.perform_for_all_matches(
        |m| {
            // runtime list
            if let Game::Match(ref mut gm) = *m {
                if gm.match_stamp().mark == mark {
                    f(gm);
                }
            }
        },
        None,
    );
    // if we have called `f` above - don't execute lines below.
    let tx = self.match_tx.clone();
    GamesDatabase::perform_for_match_with_mark(mark, |ms| {
        // database
        self.perform_for_all_matches(
            |m| {
                if let Game::Match(ref gm) = *m {
                    if gm.match_stamp().id == ms.id {
                        f(&mut GameMatch::new_with_match_stamp(
                            tx.clone(),
                            ms.clone(),
                            gm.needs_server_set,
                            gm.server_id,
                        ))
                    }
                }
            },
            None,
        );
    });
}
```

We have to operate on objects from the database only if we were unable to find them in runtime list. That is why I decided to make a variable which says "we already found these objects in the list, leave the database alone".

Comment: Note that the whole point of the closure being declared `Fn` is to only allow those that don't modify the state they capture. (This in turn makes them acceptable in multi-threaded and other contexts.) Using `Fn` is the most liberal option regarding where  you *use* the closure, but the most conservative option regarding what kind of closures you *accept*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change your `perform_for_all` function to use [`FnMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html) instead of [`Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html):

```
fn perform_for_all<F>(&mut self, mut f: F)
where
    F: FnMut(&mut u64),
{
    for mut i in &mut self.vec {
        f(&mut i);
    }
}
```

[As Peter said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41240890/2319934), there is some compiler magic going on.

The signature for [`Fn::call`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html#tymethod.call) is:

```
extern "rust-call" fn call(&self, args: Args) -> Self::Output
```

This takes an immutable reference to `self`, which is why you can't modify any of the captured variables.

The signature for [`FnMut::call_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html#tymethod.call_mut) lets you mutate variables because it takes `&mut self`:

```
extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, args: Args) -> Self::Output
```

By changing your closure from `Fn` to `FnMut`, you allow it to modify its captured variables, given that the references you pass to it are mutable.

Comment: Well, I have just tried using `Rc<RefCell<bool>>` and it works too. Could you also include this into your answer with explanation why did it work ?

Comment: @Victor your `Rc<RefCell<T>>` works, because that way you're obtaining a shared mutable reference to `T`. Even though that works, it's far from the best solution. I edited my answer to show how/why the `FnMut` works.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy `Rc<RefCell<bool>>` is a hack because it hides mutability from Rust's static analyzer, and for no good reason. For example, using it in to allow `Fn` to mutate state will allow the closure to be invoked from multiple threads, but it will panic (abort the thread) at run-time if two threads try to execute the closure at the same time. Why do you need the function declared `Fn` as opposed to `FnMut`?

Answer (score 10):

Just to expand a little on SplittyDev's answer.

When you use a closure, the compiler does some magic to let the closure access variables in its environment. Effectively it will create a new struct, whose members are the variables that you tried to access.

It's not exactly this (which won't actually compile), but it's a reasonable approximation conceptually:

```
struct Closure_1 {
    done: bool
}

impl FnMut<&mut u64> for Closure_1 {
    fn call_mut(&mut self, v: &mut u64) {
        println!("value: {:?}", v);                                                                 
        self.done = true;         
    }
}
```

And when you call it, those variables will be borrowed or copied (or moved if you use `move` keyword).

```
let mut c1 = Closure_1 { done : done };
a.perform_for_all(|v| c1.call(&v)); 
done = c1.done;
```

When the closure modifies its environment, it cannot be a `Fn` because it must also mutate the variables on itself:

```
impl Fn<&mut u64> for Closure_1 {
    fn call(&self, v: &mut u64) {
        println!("value: {:?}", v);                                                                 
        self.done = true; // Can't do this because self is not a mutable ref
    }
}
```

See *The Rust Programming Language* [section on closures and their environment](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/closures.html#closures-and-their-environment) for more information.

Comment: Could you add a link to "magic" in the source code or expand on it some more? I think it is quite central for developing an intuition (and advancing understanding).

Comment: Added a link to the documentation. This explains it pretty well, though doesn't go into details of what the struct actually looks like.

Comment: I was more referring to compiler code that does the said "magic". I'm curious how `done` becomes `self.done` in your analogy. I understand this is for illustration and not what actually happens, so I'm looking for what actually happens.

Comment: @naktinis There is some discussion of this in the some of the compiler source comments: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/ff261d3a6b5964e1e3744d055238de624afc5d76/src/librustc/ty/sty.rs#L183, though may not be exactly what you are after.